# Dimension of the solution space of a real analytic system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, analyticity, analytic-functions

I am dealing with the following situation:

I have a real analytic system of equations, $F(x,t)=0$, with $F: [0,1]^n \times [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $.

I know that only a single solution, $x_0$ exists for $t=0$, and that this solution $(x_0,0)$ is not a critical point of $F$. This means that also for $t$ sufficiently small, a unique solution exists.
 No other solutions exist on the boundary of the domain.

I wish to show that for any given $t>0$, only isolated solutions exist.

(If I'm not mistaken, this also implies that the solution space to $F(x,t)=0$ consists of (possibly intersecting) curves and isolated points only. And, that the vector field spanned by $F$ for any fixed $t$ has isolated equilibria only - please correct if necessary).

I realize that one way forward is considering the Jacobian of $F$ and the points where it does not have full rank; but so far that has not proven very fruitful, as this just shifts the problem to showing that the system of its subdeterminants only has isolated solutions - in the given case, that does not seem to be easier.
If I'm not mistaken, the property I'm looking should be generic due to Sard's theorem - unfortunately that is not enough for my purposes.

Are there any other approaches or results that could be promising?

I feel that the [Identity theorem for real analytic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739476/the-identity-theorem-for-real-analytic-functions) might be of help, but I'm having trouble how make use of it here.

Edit: [This question on zero sets of real analytic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2692780/zero-sets-of-real-analytic-functions-of-several-variables) is likely related as well. Still trying to understand if and how the discussion and sources cited there might help for my problem.

Happy to fill in more details on $F$ if helpful.